# Is there a way to delete/merge duplicate tags?

Tags: support, tags, burninate-system

I noticed three duplicate tags is there a way to delete/merge 2 of those?

The tags in question are: [qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc), [quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center) & [hp-quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center).

Comment: Thanks @Charles I did not notice that question. Although, both the questions should be merged (is that even possible?) as this one has the correct answer and the other one a better description.

Comment: IMO, this post should be edited to be a general question about "How do I delete/merge tags?" (I could not find any in search or in the FAQ, and I think it would be useful to have around), and a new post specifically requesting this delete/merge be added. As it stands, the answers no longer match the question (now that its been tagged as a retag/burninate request), and this question will likely get closed as a duplicate of a previous merge request anyways.

Comment: Regarding those specific tags - [Merge tags \[hp-quality-center\], \[quality-center\], \[qc\], and 2 more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212091).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general procedure for tags that are in use is:

1. Make a post on meta entitled "Delete [tag]" or "Burninate [tag]" or something equally succinct and descriptive.
2. In the post, present a rationale for why the tags should be considered for deletion.
3. Tag the post as [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

If, alternatively, you'd like to request that two tags be merged (e.g. duplicate tags), you can use [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) instead of [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request).

A good example of such a post is [Burninate [derived]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196719/burninate-derived), or just look at anything in the burninate/retag request tags.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention [meta-tag:synonym-request].

Answer (score 8):

One way to remove tag is just remove the receptive tag from all the tagged question. After 24 hours all non used zombi tags get deleted by system.

[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/252811)

Another way is to post the question on meta ( which you already did ) and request for the burniate a particular tag. Moderator/developer will remove it.

[Burninate Tag Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Burninate)

Comment: Quick question. If for example you've received a badge that relates to 'tag' creation and that tag is either removed or deleted, does that mean your earned badge is removed too?

Comment: @user3315821 Dont worry about the badge. It will not get removed from your profile.

Comment: @Kedarnath Thanks for the answer. The tags are not unused. I have updated my questions to make it a tag merge/delete request. I am leaving it up to the Moderators to decide what they want to do.

Comment: People new to the tag merge process (like me) would probably benefit from reading [this comment about DIY merging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360218/merge-non-printable-with-non-printing-characters?cb=1#comment537688_360227).

Comment: What will happen to the questions which were tagged to that burninated tag?