# How to disambiguate the tag [gmt]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-disambiguation

The current definition of the tag [gmt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmt) refers to time zones only. There is the [Generic Mapping Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Mapping_Tools), also sharing this abbreviation. May somebody please

1. be so kind and add the tag **Generic Mapping Tools** and
2. guide me on how to handle the disambiguation.

The definition would be similar to the [Wikipedia entry on Generic Mapping Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Mapping_Tools).

Related posts:

- *[Is there a way to delete/merge duplicate tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250928/is-there-a-way-to-delete-merge-duplicate-tags)*

Comment: The real questions is why do you need a **Generic Mapping Tools** tag? As it does not really focus a tool, imo it will lead questions to be ambiguous/too broad/unclear.

Comment: The [GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmt) has this tag. Questions about these tools are probably better asked there.

Comment: @B--rian we have [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone) and [utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utc) but luckily no CET, CST, EST, but oh, we have [PST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pst)

Comment: @rene We should probably make tags for all the timezones. How many could there be? ;)

Comment: [A search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgmt%5D++mapping+tools) shows 5 questions tagged with [gmt] that are about mapping tools.

Answer (score 4):

So far there is no evidence that "GMT" is used for significant number of posts that are outside "GMT as timezone". Unless there are many on-topic posts (at least 20+, preferably hundreds) we don't really have this problem of disambiguation.

Based on [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgmt%5D++mapping+tools) from [Cecilia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3303546/cecilia) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355475/how-to-disambiguate-the-tag-gmt/355511#comment506855_355475) there are about 5 questions now and none of them look related to programming. As Bill the Lizard [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355475/how-to-disambiguate-the-tag-gmt#comment506655_355475) such questions more likely be on-topic on [GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmt).

For on-topic questions about Generic Mapping Tools using [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis) tag would be appropriate.

The only real actions for "gmt" tag are: rename it to "GMT-timezone" or make synonym of UTC. If you really find *a lot of on-topic* questions about "Generic Mapping Tools" we can create new tag like "gmt-gis"

Comment: I vote for creating `gmt-gis` (and set that as synonym to `UTC`) as well as creating `gmt-timezone`.

Comment: @B--rian so far your post has no indication there is actually a problem. If you have list of existing on-topic questions about "generic mapping tools" make sure to edit it into the post and than someone may consider creating new tags. Without it I see no action needed.

Comment: Understood, I will create that list soon.