# Merge [non-printable] with [non-printing-characters]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Recently I noticed [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625556/what-are-the-parquet-file-special-symbol) tagged with both [non-printable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-printable)
 and [non-printing-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-printing-characters). I took a look at them, and tagging with both is pretty common (though not universal). I'd suggest merging these two small tags, or perhaps non-printable as a synonym for non-printing-characters?

Comment: Suggested title: "What I think about duplicate tags is [non-printable]."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've done a review of [non-printable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-printable) for questions about other content that cannot be printed, and identified just [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882581/pdfbox-not-recognising-pdf-to-be-non-printable) that's not about non-printable characters, and should get retagged after the merge

The rest of the content is all about non-printing characters, so merge away!

Comment: Thanks! I hear no protests, printable or otherwise, so I'll make it happen.

Comment: @RichChurcher Just FYI: Merging tags is usually a task for a moderator. They have tools specifically for merging tags.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that. Since there were so few tags involved, I'd just been editing the tags on each question.

Comment: Yup, avoid merging yourself. This question probably has been noticed by one of the mods, but on the off-chance it hasn't, you can mod-flag it.